# jQuery change date format form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have one function that needs to select dates and show it in link (after press button Submit) like this

> ?date_from=2018-09-18&date_to=2018-10-09

But problem is in input, where I have to select dates format is like 18-Sep-2018, so I have to format this `18-Sep-2018` to `2018-10-18`, but still have to show like `18-Sep-2018` in input.

**Here is the code**

```
<form class="rates">
    <div class="date-range date-range-main">
        @include('components/input_date', [
            'name' => 'date_from',
            'inline' => TRUE,
            'value' => $date_range->get_start(),
            'label' => ''
        ])
        -
        @include('components/input_date', [
            'name' => 'date_to',
            'inline' => TRUE,
            'value' => $date_range->get_end(),
            'label' => ''
        ])
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        {{uctrans('labels.search')}}
    </button>
</form>
```

So now when I run this function link is like

> ?date_from=30+Oct+2018&date_to=20+Nov+2018

and it needs to be like

> ?date_from=2018-11-20&date_to=2018-12-11

Comment: Where is JavaScript / jQuery and PHP Code?

Comment: Try this date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_range->get_start()))

Comment: @NithinMohan He said it still need to show like `18-Sep-2018` in input.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can do something like this.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.rates', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    var form = $(document.createElement('form'));
    $(form).attr("action", "");

    var dt1 = new Date($('input[name="date_from"]').val());
    var dt2 = new Date($('input[name="date_from"]').val());

    var input1 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "date_from").val(dt1.getFullYear() + "-" + (dt1.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dt1.getDate());
    var input2 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "date_to").val(dt2.getFullYear() + "-" + (dt2.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dt2.getDate());

    $(form).append($(input1));
    $(form).append($(input2));

    form.appendTo( document.body );

    $(form).submit();

    return false;
});
```

In jquery we can create a hidden form and format the input and submit the new form.

Comment: This is doing something. But when i try to select 'date_to' it is giving me same date as date_from. And only date_from can be changed and it is the same in date_to.

Comment: @RadeComet Can you please accept this answer if it's really help you.